# Создание игровых юнитов

Tags: java, c++, c#

К примеру, есть класс Warrior и я хочу сделать X объектов. В какой список их лучше поместить, вектор?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы помещал в лист, и итератором при необходимости обходил его. 
Смотри при добавлении в вектор нового элемента выделяется новый участок памяти в который копируются старые элементы и новый и так же с удалением, а в листе удаление и добавление происходит на порядок быстрее.

Вот даже [почитать](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/cpp/segmented_list.xml)
 можешь на эту тему

Comment: Мне кажется не совсем удачной ссылка... Все-таки там автор пишет о разработке текстового редактора, и, соответственно, задачи вставки/удаления текста накладывают свои требования на список. В данном же случае, подойдет простой односвязный (или двусвязный, в зависимости от необходимости и удобства) список...

Comment: И сколько времени займет обход этого списка и прорисовка объектов?

Comment: Время выполнения обхода порядка O(N), а добавления и вставки элементов O(1)

Answer (score 2):

Односвязный список (list). Тем более что у Вас наверняка будут не только Warrior'ы но и другие игровые персонажи/объекты, нуждающиеся в обработке каждую итерацию игрового цикла. На мой взгляд, лучше всего было бы реализовать некий базовый класс (интерфейс типа IGameObject), в котором были бы заранее размечены виртуальные функции типа GameTick и т.п. При такой организации Вам не придется отдельно обрабатывать списки зданий, отдельно воинов и т.д. Просто, для каждого объекта вызовете функцию GameTick... А C++ и полиморфизм позаботятся об остальном. Единственное "но" - не забывайте освобождать *всю* память выделенную выбывающим из игры объектам...

К вопросу о программировании игр могу посоветовать [Noel Llopis. "C++ For Game Programmers"](http://www.amazon.com/C-Game-Programmers-Development/dp/1584502274) (можно найти и скачать pdf), к сожалению на английском, однако подход мне очень понравился. И еще вот эту [Ron Penton. "Data structures for game programmers"](http://www.amazon.com/Structures-Programmers-Premier-Press-Development/dp/1931841942) - тоже, на мой взгляд, очень хорошая книга...

Comment: Упомянутые авторы в соответствующих книгах не объясняют как рисовать с помощью ДиректХ, а излагают "основы" которые помогут Вам писать качественный и быстрый код..... И, соответственно, лучше понять раскрываемую тематику.

Answer (score 1):

В C# я бы завёл ArrayList и кидал бы туда обеъкты.
Тогда обход выглядил бы так (a - ArrayList):

```
foreach (Warrior w in a){
    w.position.X += 10; //например
}
```

Answer (score 0):

если Вы серьезно решили заниматься играми, то лучше смотреть в сторону готовых игровых движков - **http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_engine**
там подобные операции и списки уже задействованы, а программер занимается более абстрактными вопросами, не погружаясь в такие низкоуровневые детали

например: (простите за С#)

```
TempWarrior warrior = createWarriorTemplateFromModel("WARRIOR_MODEL");

warrior.attackMode = true;

warrior.color = Colors.RED;

EngineService.populateGrid(warrior, 10, 10, 100); // заполнить сетку 10*10, смещение XY = 100
```

Comment: Позвольте с Вами не согласиться. Если автор вопроса решил действительно серьезно заняться играми, то, в первую очередь, ему нужно самому понять, что и как происходит в игровом движке, чтобы в дальнейшем, даже при работе с движками третьих производителей, не возникало вопросов "а почему надо так, а не так?"...

Comment: Не спорю, знание движка архи полезная вещь, при текущем уровне алгоритмики, когда есть сомнения в выборе спискового типа, цель - "написание игры" будет гораздо ближе при изучении движка, а ковыряние в его кишках могут только запутать, обычно авторами указаны методики применения, при которых кишки пашут идеально.

Поверите или нет, но при написании своей мало-мальски внятной игры, этот вопрос (применение списка) будет самым легким, и последующие (встающие) алгоритмические задачи, могут уже даже не вписываться в формат данного сайта.